# Equivalent norms on $\Bbb{R}^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, compactness, equivalent-metrics

I just want my proof checked that all norms on $\mathbb{R}$ are equivalent to the Euclidean norm. It's as follows:

Let $||\cdot || $be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n .\ $Define $f:S^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n, x\mapsto ||x||.$ Let $ \{ e_j \}_{j=1}^{n}  $ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n $ Let $S$ denote $S^{n-1}$ for ease.
Now, $f \ $  is continuous since $$||f(x)-f(y)||\leq ||\sum_{j=1}^{n} (x_j-y_j)e_j ||\leq n ||x-y||_{\infty}\leq n||x-y||_2 \ .$$
Now $f$ is continuous and $S$ is compact so by the extreme value theorem there are $C_1, C_2 \geq 0 $ such that $$C_1\leq ||x|| \leq C_2 \ .$$
We must have $C_1>0 $ as otherwise $f(x)=||x||=0 $ for some $x\in S$ but this means $x=0$ which is impossible.
Now for any $x\in S$ we have $x=y/||y||_2 $ for some non zero $y\in \mathbb{R}^n .$
So $$C_1\leq \frac{||y||}{||y||_2} \leq C_2 $$ for all non zero $y$ and so
$$C_1||y||_2\leq ||y|| \leq ||C_2 ||y||_2 $$ holds for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^n $.

Is this ok?

Comment: The function $f$ makes no sense. If $f(x)=\|x\|$, then $f$ is a function from $S^{n-1}$ into $\Bbb R$, not into $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Except for the mistake pointed out by Jose Carlos Santos your proof is correct and it is very standard.

Comment: Yes I meant a function into $\mathbb{R}$